# Openfiledialog safefilenames

Tags: c#, winforms

I have being trying to display the filenames for the multiple files that have been opened using the file dialog. I have been doing this by a for loop but I have had no luck.

```
foreach (string value in openFileDialog.SafeFileNames)
      Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: no luck with what? what happened?

Comment: How is the dialog opened and closed?

Comment: Programming isnt about luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to iterate through your selected filenames.

Check if your user has NOT cancelled the dialog with `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK`

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, For some reason I just get the very last filename.

Comment: Thanks for your response dknaack, your solution did not work for my situation due to some of my other coding. However, I ended up extracting the path of the file and then the filename which works for me. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! Have a nice day. All the best!